# Intent extras sent with ACTION_CALL?

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I've got an app going that basically lists some people and you click their row/name to call them, like so:

```
String tel = "tel:" + temp.getPhone();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(tel))
```

But I would like it if the person who receives the call could see from the caller id (or some way) that the call originated from my app. Like override the caller id or append it with a phone number extension or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. Most phones use GSM standard, and nothing like that is part of it, only caller's number is available.

Also imagine people using old nokias or smth. How would they see your additional info?

Answer (score 0):

You can show your incomming/outgoing call dialog over (top most) default UI of android but can not replace or override it.

You can use WindowsManager to control that as add your Activity on top of screen.